# sparklyr and microbenchmark

Tags: r, sparklyr, microbenchmark

Consider the following: I create a `df_tbl` with 1,000,000 rows. Large enough such that computation time isn't trivially fast.

I put the dataframe into Spark, and perform computations with the dataframe held in RAM, and the Spark dataframe.

Microbenchmark suggests that the computation with the Spark dataframe is faster, as would be expected, yet, when I'm programming interactively the computation involving the Spark dataframe is noticeably slower to return a result.

I'm curious as to what is going on. Example code given below:

```r
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
#> * Using Spark: 2.2.0


# main --------------------------------------------------------------------

N <- 1000000

df <- data_frame(
  CASENO = 1000001:(1000000 + N),
  sex    = sample(1:2, N, rep = TRUE),
  group  = sample(1:5, N, rep = TRUE),
  x      = abs(rnorm(N)),
  y      = rnorm(N),
  z      = rnorm(N)
)


spark_df <- sdf_copy_to(sc, df, "spark_df", memory = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE)

benchmark <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  df %>% group_by(sex, group) %>% summarise(sum_x = sum(x)) %>% mutate(prop = sum_x/sum(sum_x)),
  spark_df %>% group_by(sex, group) %>% summarise(sum_x = sum(x)) %>% mutate(prop = sum_x/sum(sum_x))
)

summary(benchmark)
#>                                                                                                       expr
#> 1       df %>% group_by(sex, group) %>% summarise(sum_x = sum(x)) %>%      mutate(prop = sum_x/sum(sum_x))
#> 2 spark_df %>% group_by(sex, group) %>% summarise(sum_x = sum(x)) %>%      mutate(prop = sum_x/sum(sum_x))
#>        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#> 1 36.92519 39.119954 43.993727 41.522914 45.885576 107.71227   100
#> 2  1.12158  1.279999  1.855679  1.423407  1.551012  20.22911   100

start1 <- proc.time()
df %>% group_by(sex, group) %>% summarise(sum_x = sum(x)) %>% mutate(prop = sum_x/sum(sum_x))
end1 <- proc.time() - start1

start2 <- proc.time()
spark_df %>% group_by(sex, group) %>% summarise(sum_x = sum(x)) %>% mutate(prop = sum_x/sum(sum_x))
end2 <- proc.time() - start2

end1
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.33    0.04    0.37

end2
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.18    0.00    7.51 

Created on 2018-03-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).
```

Comment: My two cents. The `user time` is the CPU time charged for the execution of the current R session, and these times are somehow similar in both cases. However, although with the "pure R" implementation the calculations can be performed "right away", with Spark, a lot of things need to be done in advance (manage the connection, data transfers, I/O operations, etc.) with delay times that may not be reflected on the user and system times, but might have an impact on the whole operation time...